# AJAX Post request working only on Web Console (Preview)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a really simple ajax request to "send" the ID of an element the user clicks on the webSite. The script is working only on the Web Console (in the Network -> Preview section). This happens in every browser.

here's the code:

***AJAX REQUEST***

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $('.point1, .point2, .point3, .point4, .point5, .point6, .point7').click(function(event) {
  var itemid = event.target.id; 

     $.ajax({
           type: 'post',
           //url: "index.php",
           data: {'itemid' : itemid}, 
           cache : false,
           async : true,
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function(data) {
                      alert('success');     
           },
     failure: function(data) {
                    alert('failure');
           } 
       });
 });
 </script>
```

**PHP Function**

```html
 <?php 
  
  if(isset($_POST['itemid'])){
        $itemid = $_POST['itemid'];

  echo "success";
  $itemid = (int)$itemid;
  echo $itemid;
    } else{
 echo "failure";}
  
  ?>
```

Can you help me with this?

Just adding the image to let you understand better.

UPDATED: Here's the full code, hope it's not too confusionary (still a beginner):

I'm getting the response correct but echo json_encode($d); is not printing.
Btw thank you very much for your support :)

```html
<?php
$d = array();
if(isset($_POST['itemid'])){
  if($_POST['itemid'] != ""){
    $d['result'] = "success";
    $d['itemid'] = (int)$_POST['itemid'];
  } else{
    $d['result'] = "error";
    $d['error'] = "'itemid' was not set.";
  }
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($d);
  exit();
}

if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off'){
  // La richiesta e' stata fatta su HTTPS
} else {
  // Redirect su HTTPS
  // eventuale distruzione sessione e cookie relativo
  $redirect = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .
  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
  exit();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" type="text/css">
<?php
setcookie('test', 1, time()+3600);

if(!isset($_GET['cookies'])){
    include_once "../header.php";
    include_once '../footer.php';
    include_once '../right_column.php';

    echo"<script type='text/javascript'></script>\r\n<noscript>JavaScript is off. Please enable to view full site.</noscript>";
} else {
    echo "No Cookies";
}
?>
<div class="map">
  <div class="point1" id="1"> </div>
  <div class="point2" id="2"> </div>
  <div class="point3" id="3"> </div>
  <div class="point4" id="4"> </div>
  <div class="point5" id="5"> </div>
  <div class="point6" id="6"> </div>
  <div class="point7" id="7"> </div>
</div> 
<?php
    $green='rgb(30,255,0)';     
    $yellow='rgb(255,255,0)';
    $red='rgb(255,0,0)';    

    include '../includes/dbhinc.php';

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {   
        $sql="SELECT nummot, numbici FROM grid WHERE cellaid='$i'";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $moto=$row["nummot"];
        $bici=$row["numbici"];

        $mezzi=$moto+$bici;

        if($mezzi>=4){
            $color=$green;
            $sql="UPDATE `grid` SET `rgb`='rgb(30,255,0)' WHERE cellaid = $i";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
            echo "<script> document.getElementById('$i').style.backgroundColor ='rgb(30,255,0)' </script>";
        } else if($mezzi<4 && $mezzi>0){
            $color=$yellow;
            $sql="UPDATE `grid` SET `rgb`='rgb(255,255,0)' WHERE cellaid = $i";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
            echo"<script> document.getElementById('$i').style.backgroundColor ='rgb(255,255,0)' </script>";
        }   else{   
            $color=$red;
            $sql="UPDATE `grid` SET `rgb`='rgb(255,0,0)' WHERE cellaid = $i";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
            echo"<script> document.getElementById('$i').style.backgroundColor ='rgb(255,0,0)' </script>";
        }
}   
?>  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".point1, .point2, .point3, .point4, .point5, .point6, .point7").click(function(event) {
    var itemid = $(this).attr("id");    

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "index.php",
    data: {
      'itemid': itemid
    }, 
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      if(data.result == "success"){
        console.log("Success", data.itemid);
      } else {
        console.log("Failed", data);
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
<?php       
 
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\r\n";
  echo "$('.point1, .point2, .point3, .point4, .point5, .point6, .point7').click(function(event) {\r\n";
        echo "\talert('itemid');\r\n";
        echo "\tvar itemid = event.target.id;\r\n";
        echo "});\r\n";
  echo "</script>";


    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 120)) {
                    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
                    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
                    header("Location: index.php");
        }

        $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();        
  
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\r\n";
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Inserisci qui il n°di Bici da prenotare <input type='number' id='bicidapren' method='post'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Inserisci qui il n°di Moto da prenotare <input type='number' id='motodapren' method='post'> <button id='tryit' onclick='myFunction()'>Confirm</button>";
        echo "function myFunction() {\r\n";
        echo "\tBicidaprenotare = parseInt(document.getElementById('bicidapren').value)-1;\r\n";
        echo "\tMotodaprenotare = parseInt(document.getElementById('motodapren').value)-1;\r\n";
        echo "}\r\n";
        echo "</script>";
        }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, do you mean you can see the network call being made but the backend isnt handling it like you expected?

Comment: I see the newtork call being made and on the Preview Tab the function is working as I intended: echoing the $itemid in the PHP part

Comment: PHP will always respond; it will return a `200` status. You have to look at the content of the response.

Comment: You should probably do a form post rather than an ajax request.

Comment: Ok, I get the 200 status but also in the Preview Tab the webpage is correct after I click an element. I don't know how to say it better :(

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

**JavaScript**

```
$("[class*='point']").click(function(e) {
  var itemid = $(this).attr("id");  

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "index.php?",
    data: {
      'itemid': itemid
    }, 
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      if(data.result == "success"){
        console.log("Success", data.itemid);
      } else {
        console.log("Failed", data);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$d = array();
if(isset($_POST['itemid'])){
  $d['result'] = "success";
  $d['itemid'] = (int)$_POST['itemid'];
} else{
  $d['result'] = "error";
  $d['error'] = "'itemid' was not set.";
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($d);
?>
```

In a lot of cases, it's better to pass JSON data back. It's easier for JavaScript to handle it. So we build an array of data that we want to pass back to AJAX request and encode it as JSON.

When we make the AJAX Post, PHP will result in a Successful response. You're welcome to catch an error, this would happen with `400` or `500` Status result from the PHP call. You can also see this in your Web Console.

We're going to get a JSON Object back from PHP, either:

```
{
  result: "success",
  itemid: 2
}
```

Or:

```
{
  result: "error",
  error: "'itemid' was not set."
}
```

In JavaScript, we can use dot notation to access the elements of the object. You can also access it like this:

```
if(data['result'] == "success")
```

Dot notation is advised.

**Update 1**

In your PHP File, you will want a different structure. You're going to have to perform some actions before the HTML is presented to the Browser.

```
<?php
$d = array();
if(isset($_POST['itemid'])){
  if($_POST['itemid'] != ""){
    $itemid = (int)$_POST['itemid'];
  } else{
    $d['result'] = "error";
    $d['error'] = "'itemid' was not set.";
  }
  $d;
  // Connect to SQL
  // Query DB for Table Data ...WHERE itemId = '$itemid'
  // Store resultset to $d
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($d);
  exit();
}

if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off'){
  // La richiesta e' stata fatta su HTTPS
} else {
  // Redirect su HTTPS
  // eventuale distruzione sessione e cookie relativo
  $redirect = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .
  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
  exit();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" type="text/css">
<?php
setcookie('test', 1, time()+3600);

if(!isset($_GET['cookies'])){
    include_once "../header.php";
    include_once "../grid.asp";
    include_once '../footer.php';
    include_once '../right_column.php';

    echo"<script type='text/javascript'></script>\r\n<noscript>JavaScript is off. Please enable to view full site.</noscript>";
} else {
    echo "No Cookies";
}
?>
<div class="map">
  <div class="point1" id="1"> </div>
  <div class="point2" id="2"> </div>
  <div class="point3" id="3"> </div>
  <div class="point4" id="4"> </div>
  <div class="point5" id="5"> </div>
  <div class="point6" id="6"> </div>
  <div class="point7" id="7"> </div>
</div> 
<?php
    $green='rgb(30,255,0)';     
    $yellow='rgb(255,255,0)';
    $red='rgb(255,0,0)';    

    include 'includes/dbhinc.php';

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {   
        $sql="SELECT nummot, numbici FROM grid WHERE cellaid='$i'";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $moto=$row["nummot"];
        $bici=$row["numbici"];

        $mezzi=$moto+$bici;

        if($mezzi>=4){
            $color=$green;
            $sql="UPDATE `grid` SET `rgb`='rgb(30,255,0)' WHERE cellaid = $i";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
            echo "<script> document.getElementById('$i').style.backgroundColor ='rgb(30,255,0)' </script>";
        } else if($mezzi<4 && $mezzi>0){
            $color=$yellow;
            $sql="UPDATE `grid` SET `rgb`='rgb(255,255,0)' WHERE cellaid = $i";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
            echo"<script> document.getElementById('$i').style.backgroundColor ='rgb(255,255,0)' </script>";
        }   else{   
            $color=$red;
            $sql="UPDATE `grid` SET `rgb`='rgb(255,0,0)' WHERE cellaid = $i";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
            echo"<script> document.getElementById('$i').style.backgroundColor ='rgb(255,0,0)' </script>";
        }
}   
?>  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".point1, .point2, .point3, .point4, .point5, .point6, .point7").click(function(event) {
    var itemid = $(this).attr("id");    

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "index.php?",
    data: {
      'itemid': itemid
    }, 
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      if(data.result == "success"){
        console.log("Success", data.itemid);
      } else {
        console.log("Failed", data);
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
<?php       
    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 120)) {
                    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
                    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
                    header("Location: index.php");
        }

        $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();        

        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Inserisci qui il n°di Bici da prenotare <input type='number' id='bicidapren' method='post'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Inserisci qui il n°di Moto da prenotare <input type='number' id='motodapren' method='post'> <button id='tryit' onclick='myFunction()'>Confirm</button>";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\r\n";
        echo "$('.point1, .point2, .point3, .point4, .point5, .point6, .point7').click(function(event) {\r\n";
        echo "\talert('itemid');\r\n"
        echo "\tvar itemid = event.target.id;\r\n";
      echo "});\r\n";   
        echo "function myFunction() {\r\n";
        echo "\tBicidaprenotare = parseInt(document.getElementById('bicidapren').value)-1;\r\n";
        echo "\tMotodaprenotare = parseInt(document.getElementById('motodapren').value)-1;\r\n";
        echo "}\r\n";
        echo "</script>";
        }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, the code is working but I'm getting the same problem.
I have to delete this part: header('Content-Type: application/json');
for this error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: @Scallo this does not make sense. You should not need to `JSON.parse()` if you're passing JSON data from the PHP. I think you should update your question to include your latest code.

Comment: I am not, I copypasted your ajax code. If I keep the line header('Content-Type:...') I get that error, if I don't keep it I have the same problem of the webconsole.
Maybe I have something wrong somewhere else

Comment: @Scallo when you review the response in console, what do you see?

Comment: on the webpage I get {"result":"error","error":"'itemid' was not set."}, in the response tab I get: {"result":"success","itemid":3}
I had to delete the line header('Content-Type: application/json'); for the error
Btw, thank you very much for your support

Comment: @Scallo those are the expected results. Something is missing. Please update your post and include your current code.

Comment: @Scallo thanks for the update. Since your posting data back to itself, the results are not as you expected. You'll want to move all the PHP to be pre-HTML or into a seperate PHP File.

Comment: The fact is that I can't reload the page while doing this script, so I don't know if I can separate the PHP file. I will try to move all the PHP to be pre-HTML

Comment: @Scallo I updated my answer. There is a lot you need to consider and learn about PHP and JavaScript. Mainly the idea that PHP is processed before it's passed to the browser.

Comment: @Scallo great! If this answers your question, hit the Mark and feel free to Upvote too.

Comment: I'm still unable to get itemid as a php variable: echo json_encode($d); is not echoing

Comment: @Scallo what are you seeing in the console response?

Comment: This: {"result":"success","itemid":7}
Maybe is a xampp problem? A firefox problem?

Comment: @Scallo this would suggest that the PHP Script is getting the data and assigning the value to `$d['itemid']` and then exiting the script. The value is passed back to your JavaScript (and is no longer in PHP Memory). It';s not clear what you want to accomplish with this data. You could write it to Database or add it to Session data. Please clarify what it is you want to accomplish.

Comment: With the itemid:_ I need to make a SQL Query to extract some information of the element from the database (KeyID = ItemID) and then print the information in the webpage.
In short: you click the element, you can see the info about this element in my database

Comment: @Scallo I would move this to it's own PHP Script. You can still call it via AJAX and get the data from it. This script will need to check for posted data, if it exists, connects to the SQL DB and executes a SELECT script with the data, and returns it in JSON to the AJAX script.

Comment: So, I got the id from the first ajax in the javascript; then inside the PHP Script I get from the database the info I want, then I pass them to another Javascript and then I can print the info I extraced. If I am understanding correctly

Comment: Thank you for your support, I will come back to you tomorrow if you are still available

Answer (score 0):

Here is what can work for you. If it does not work then please share your entire code and the response from PHP too.

```
// jQuery AJAX call should be something like this
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    data: {
        "itemid": itemid
    },
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json) {
        if(json.success) {
            alert("Item ID is " + json.itemid);
        } else {
            alert("Item ID is " + json.itemid);
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
    }
});


// PHP code can be like this
if(isset($_POST['itemid'])){
    $itemid = $_POST['itemid'];
    echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'itemid' => $itemid]);
} else {
    echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'itemid' => 'Not available']);
}
```

Comment: I copypasted your code and added and the error function returns me this:
Error :: parsererror :: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data 

I have something wrong somewhere

Comment: Please share your entire code snippet. It will be helpful in debugging your issue.

Comment: Hi @Scallo it was a typo in my code, I have edited my answer above. By mistake, I added echo 2 times on the last line. Please refer to the correct PHP code above. I verified on my localhost and it works fine now.

Comment: Thanks for your support, I re-copied but again I'm getting the SyntaxError: JSON.Parse.

Comment: Looks like you are missing something, please try this, it's my working code.

https://www.screencast.com/t/MHul3RuLp

https://www.screencast.com/t/O06C7UhDXwhk

Comment: I tried: var itemid=1 and deleting the click function for the document.ready as you put in the images but I still get the JSON.Parse error. The error is somewhere else :( but I don't understand

Comment: No problem, I will help to debug it. Please share your entire code.

Comment: For testing your code on my localhost, I removed your code for database operations and everything is working perfectly fine for me. Please check these screenshots and try to delete and check if some other code is resulting in error. You may have to test by deleting one or more lines and check if it works or not. First try with teh code snippet that is working for me. https://www.screencast.com/t/yBaZnVSte
https://www.screencast.com/t/K9rff0zTVHD

Comment: I tried your code, but still I can't get the itemid echoed in the webPage. I am not getting any error, the response is correct If I check in the webconsole

Comment: You may need to first verify if your AJAX call is able to send the selected itemid and that your PHP code is able to return the selected itemid. Reference: https://www.screencast.com/t/EVGCScpfmWM
https://www.screencast.com/t/LX2YL0qh    and if everything appears to be same as shown then there must be something wrong in your other code on the page. Try deleting some code and test for the expected results.

Comment: Thank you for your support, I will come back to you tomorrow if you are still available